# Syncing iCal with Outlook2011

Tags: data-synchronization, ms-office, ical

No matter what I do, I can't get new items that I add to Outlook 2011 calendar to actually show up in iCal. Is this a bug? Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: How are you syncing it? Is it an iCloud, MS Exchange calendar, Gmail, or something?

Comment: Is is an Outlook 2011 Calendar and I'm actually not quite sure "how". I just want to make it so that when I add an event to my Outlook 2011 Calendar, it automatically syncs with iCal on my Mac...

Answer (score 1):

To set up iCal calendars, open iCal > select **iCal** menu > **Preferences** > **Accounts** > **"+"** below account list, then add your email account used in MS Outlook. As long as it is a IMAP email account, this should enable the calendar in iCal. It also should sync automatically.